# If not for lazy initialisation, is there any advantage of building singleton using method rather than static class member?

Tags: java

Very often I see singleton built in this way:

```
public static MyClass instance() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new MyClass();
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

If not for the lazy initialization effect, does the approach have any advantage over simply declaring a static instance like this?

```
public final static MyClass singleton = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Apart from the lazy initialisation, the main difference between the two approaches is that the former is not thread safe. Avoid it if you can.

Comment: It also won't work, as it's an instance method...

Comment: @JonSkeet typo fixed, thanks for noticing

Comment: There is often not even a benefit of explicit lazy initialization since Java's built-in lazy loading of classes will in typical scenarios happen at the same time you call the `instance()` method. Useful only if you want to decouple / delay singleton initialization from class initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in fact the other approach, i.e.:

```
public final static MyClass singleton = new MyClass();
```

might be better as, if you you have 2 threads calling the instance method at the same time you could get a race condition.

This is how Java in Practice says to do singletons:

```
  private final static MyClass _instance = new MyClass();

  public static MyClass getInstance() {
    return _instance;
  }

  private MyClass() {}
```

*Update* Since @jon-skeet mentioned it there is really good discussion of Singletons in the book Effective Java by Joshua Block. One thing he points out is that if you want your Singleton to be serializable you can't just implement Serializable. You need to override the readResolve method as well. Use the above approach makes this easy:

```
private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
  return _instance;
}
```

*Update 2*: Checkout this excellent discussion on Singletons linked to by @mardavi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization_On_Demand_Holder_Idiom

Comment: Alternative, use an enum with a single value, as recommended in Effective Java.

Comment: Personally, I like [Initialization On Demand Holder Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization_On_Demand_Holder_Idiom)

Comment: @mardavi I had forgotten about that. I used to use that all the time too. The advantage of that pattern is that the singleton is lazy initialized right?

Comment: Yes, it is "as lazy as it can be". Plus, it does not require special language constructs, which sometimes can be important (at least, I find easier to read code without special words - forgive the generic term word please)